# C++ - How to determine the type of the return value of a function?

Tags: c++, templates, types

I'm trying to build a vector of objects that have two properties, the key is always a String, and the value is always of type T

When I iterate through the vector, I need to be able to determine the type of the value property so that I can switch in a case statement to process it.

How do I determine the type of the return value of value get function of the vector object?

My class is here:

```
template <class T>
class IEFIAttribute
{
    String key;
    T value;
    public: 
            IEFIAttribute(String key, T value)
            {
                this->key = key;
                this->value = value;
            }
            String getKey();
            T getValue();
};

template <class T>
String IEFIAttribute<T>::getKey()
{
    return this->key;
}

template <class T>
T IEFIAttribute<T>::getValue()
{
    return this->value;
}
```

And in my main.cpp, the following works:

```
...
                IEFIAttribute <String> att("testkey","testvalue");

                Serial.println("XXX Key: "+att.getKey());
                Serial.println("XXX Value: "+att.getValue());
...
```

The result of running that is:

```
XXX Key: testkey
XXX Value: testvalue
```

What I want to be able to do is switch on the type of `att.getValue()` so that if it is a String, I do one thing, if it is xyz object, I process it according to my rules for xyz objects.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Kind regards!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You could used specialized templates

Comment: What are specialised templates? This is the smallest reproducable class that I could write, it only has two private values and two methods, surely it's not difficult determining the type of a return value of a function, I'm coming from C# and after 6 weeks solid of writing C++ code, this one's got me flabbergasted.

Comment: @Xamtastic You can use [`std::result_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) but you may find using that information harder or less useful than you expect. You may be better off just always making sure your `T` type always allows concatenation with string objects.

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. I can't copy this code into my editor and compile it.

Comment: I'll just throw out that this screams `std::unordered_map` to me, and not `std::vector`. Any STL map, really.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasSablik I've created the minimal reproducible example and added it as an edit, it is my first post, so thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

using String = std::string;

template<class T>
class IEFIAttribute {
public:
    using value_type = T;   // add this to be able to query it later

    IEFIAttribute(const String& Key, const T& Value) : 
        key(Key),           // prefer using the member initializer list
        value(Value) 
    {}

    // instead of copies, return const references
    String const& getKey() const {
        return key;
    };
    T const& getValue() const {
        return value;
    }

private:
    String key;
    T value;
};
```

You have many possibilities to do special handling for certain types.

A template using *constexpr if*:

```
template<typename T>
T special_1(const std::vector<IEFIAttribute<T>>& v, size_t idx) {
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, String>) {
        std::cout << "special_1() String handler\n";
    } else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
        std::cout << "special_1() int handler\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "special_1() generic handler\n";
    }
    return v[idx].getValue();
}
```

A template with specializations:

```
template<typename T>
T special_2(const std::vector<IEFIAttribute<T>>& v, size_t idx) {
    std::cout << "special_2() generic handler\n";
    return v[idx].getValue();
}

template<>
String special_2(const std::vector<IEFIAttribute<String>>& v, size_t idx) {
    std::cout << "special_2() String handler\n";
    return v[idx].getValue();
}

template<>
int special_2(const std::vector<IEFIAttribute<int>>& v, size_t idx) {
    std::cout << "special_2() int handler\n";
    return v[idx].getValue();
}
```

Or using the added `value_type` to do queries:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<IEFIAttribute<String>> v1{{"testkey", "testvalue"}};
    std::vector<IEFIAttribute<int>> v2{{"testkey", 10}};

    // decltype(v1)::value_type is the vectors value_type
    // and the second value_type is the one added to your class

    if(std::is_same_v<decltype(v1)::value_type::value_type, String>) {
        std::cout << "is String\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "is not String\n";
    }

    if(std::is_same_v<decltype(v2)::value_type::value_type, int>) {
        std::cout << "is int\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "is not int\n";
    }

    std::cout << special_1(v1, 0) << "\n";
    std::cout << special_1(v2, 0) << "\n";
    std::cout << special_2(v1, 0) << "\n";
    std::cout << special_2(v2, 0) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Splendid, indeed - may I thank you very much for taking the time, as well as additionally showing me how to improve my class by not retuning copies!

Comment: ...also note @sweenish's comment regarding `std::unordered_map`. Instead of `std::vector<IEFIAttribute<T>>` you could perhaps use `std::unordered_map<String, T>`. It has the kind of key/value relation you probably want and it's good for quick lookups.

Comment: Thanks Ted, I'm digressing to explore the unordered_map now! Meanwhile, after much ado I realised that the difficulty of a class existing in a vector but with different types T, is that it has to inherit from a base class and then the base class added to the vector ... so after much ado, the problem suddenly became about how to cast the base back into it's derived class (which is how I've edited the question, almost there but not quite!)

Comment: @Xamtastic :-) That's the way it goes sometimes. However, your question now has changed shape drastically. I suggest that you revert your edit, accept any answer that actually answered the original question and then create a new fresh question without including the legacy from this question. Put a comment here if you do open a new question. I'm still interested in looking into it.

Comment: Thanks Ted, I've reverted it as requested, the new post is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235380/spurious-characters-generated-from-templated-child-t-cast-from-parent-base-in-ve

Comment: Thanks Ted, your answer was most helpful hence I've accepted it, thank you so much for your time, and in particular, for writing so much code.

Comment: @Xamtastic Thank you very much! I took a look at your new question and gave it _one_ possible way to tackle the problem. There are as you know probably ten more ways to do it per person given the task so ... pick and choose from the good bits.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish what you need is to use a `typedef` inside your class, and then functions of `<type_traits>` for you conditional statements.

For example:

```
template <class T>
class IEFIAttribute
{
  public:
    typedef T value_type;

  // everything as before...

};
```

then

```
if (std::is_same<att::value_type, String>)
  // .. do something
```

Comment: Thanks! After much ado I realised that the difficulty of a class existing in a vector but with different types T, is that it has to inherit from a base class and then the base class added to the vector ... so after much ado, the problem suddenly became about how to cast the base back into it's derived class. But thanks for your suggestion, it added significantly to my learning curve!